# Approximation of table size for MySQL cluster

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster, size

I want to make some approximation of table size for MySQL cluster.
Please read my reasoning and tell me, if I am right or am I making mistake somewhere.

I have simple table with PK (int) and additional column (int). 
In MySQL int = 4 bytes, so one row is about 12 bytes (4*2 for columns and 4 for PK index).
If I have for example 1'000'000 rows this will be 12'000'000 bytes ~= 11.5MB.
Am I right in this calculations? Can I store such table with so little space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need some more space for row overhead and PK storage. More information you can find in [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html).

For the most detailed information you can use [ndb_size.pl](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-cluster-programs-ndb-size-pl.html) utility.

Comment: How much do you mean, when you say "some more". 20%? 50%? 100%?

Comment: Use ndb_size.pl to get full information about space needed. It depends on MySQL Cluster version if additional column can be NULL, etc.